# Python XMPP server library

Tags: python, xmpp

I know there are several libraries to connect to XMPP servers, but is there an XMPP server library somewhere written in Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMPP server in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746015/xmpp-server-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick google search reveals:

- http://code.google.com/p/pretzel/

  > An XMPP server written on the Twisted Python framework
- http://code.google.com/p/pjabberd/

  > Jabber/XMPP Server in Python

Both seem a bit unmaintained, but you might be able to get them up and running.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like that there is a new project on github:

[python-xmpp-server](https://github.com/thisismedium/python-xmpp-server)

```
An XMPP Server written in Python.
```

Personally I'm modifying it to provide an XMPP interface to the service I'm building, and I found it fairly easy to achieve this by modifying the "chat-server" example. You can write your own handlers for presence notification, roster requests, and other events.