# XMPP server in python

Tags: python, lua, xmpp

I'm looking hard but I cannot find any XMPP server in python with the following features:

- using epoll, just like http://www.gevent.org/
- supporting BOSH
- modular design
- use little RAM/CPU for up to 1000 users
- more important than the previous requirement: the CPU/RAM usage must be predictable

[Prosody](http://prosody.im/doc/modules) looks quite good feature-wise, but I don't know how many users it can support simultaneously and how it is performance-wise.

Could someone give me an idea?

Comment: Prosody is written in Lua, which may well be an option for me, although I'm primarily looking for a python solution. I'll use prosody if someone can confirm that its performance is good enough for my demands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xmpp.org uses Prosody, any other questions? :P

btw, if you want to toy with it a little, you can always run prosody using luajit (didn't test that myself, but I'm fairly sure it would work). Expect at least 2-4x faster execution.

Look @ ejabberd too.

Answer (score 3):

For a rough idea of how Prosody is performance-wise, see this post on their ML. https://groups.google.com/d/topic/prosody-users/SlXpfwJfgY4/discussion